# When can i expect "stdout" printed to console

Tags: c, linux

I know this is because of buffering of stdout but when can i expect output of stdout in the following proggram. If i run, I am always getting "stderr" as output. If i add '\n' or fflush(stdout) then only i am getting both statements. If i don't add '\n' or fflush(stdout),i am not getting "stdout" as output. when will i get all buffered "stdout"s as output if i don't add '\n' or fflush(stdout).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
      for(;;)
      {
              fprintf(stdout,"stdout");
              fprintf(stderr,"stderr");
              sleep(1);
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, a new line or a flush because by default `stdout` is line buffered when it refers a terminal device.

To be more precise: standard input and standard output are fully buffered, if and only if they do not refer to an interactive device. Standard error is never fully buffered.

About line buffering, quoting from [APUE](http://www.apuebook.com/):

> Line buffering comes with two caveats. First, the size of the buffer that the standard I/O library is using to collect each line is fixed, so I/O might take place if we fill this buffer before writing a newline. Second, whenever input is requested through the standard I/O library from either (a) an unbuffered stream or (b) a line-buffered stream (that requiresdata to be requested from the kernel), all line-buffered output streams are flushed. The reason for the qualifier on (b) is that the requested data may alreadybe 
>   in the buffer, which doesn't require data to be read from the kernel. Obviously, any input from an unbuffered stream, item (a), requires data to be obtained from the kernel.

To change it to unbuffered, use [`setvbuf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/setvbuf/):

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

Comment: my question is,if i don't add '\n' or fflush(stdout), when will this all buffered stdout's will print to console

Comment: @Chinna when the internal buffer of the stdout FILE* is full. The size of that buffer is platform dependent, though 1024 or 4096 bytes is common.

Answer (score 0):

output sent to stderr usually prints immediately.  It is the standard error output.  Errors, of course, should be displayed immediately, and so any buffer that exists is flushed immediately.

stdout, on the other hand, is buffered.  Getting that buffer to print out varies by language, but usually at least one of two things are required: `/n`, or some other type of newline character, or `.flush();`.  If you do not provide these options, then usually you have to **wait for the buffer to fill**.  This can take any amount of time, as it pretty much entirely depends on how large the buffer is.

By convention, the way streams are handled is that you shove as much information into them as you want, and then call `.flush()`.  If the buffer happens to fill up in the meantime, then the data is sent to wherever it's going and the buffer starts filling up again.

Here, though, you're filling up a buffer that takes in text.  Text does not really take up a whole lot of space compared to binary information (this is a VERY subjective statement and should be interpreted loosely), and so filling up the buffer could take quite a while.

The best practice is for you to manually flush the stream (`stdout`) once you have "fed" it all of the text you want printed.

Answer (score 0):

**fprintf** is by default line buffered.  You can alter the behavior by calling **setvbuf**. It allows you to set it to 'unbuffered', 'line buffered', or 'fully buffered'.